# Bash script to open SSH reverse tunnel at startup

Tags: linux, boot, bash, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to run a script at startup on a Debian Jessie machine, among other things it creates a SSH reverse tunnel.

The thing is that I have put this script at `if-up` and either in `rc.local` to launch from. All other jobs work fine but when it has to create the SSH tunnel either it is unable to create it or it hangs the boot on a job running message.

I would be more clear, but the thing is that if I run `/etc/rc.local` after the machine has booted, the tunnel is running perfect.

I have to add that the machine the tunnel is created to is a Raspberry Pi and sometimes I cannot ssh until I make some pings. I managed the script in order to do so, but no success at boot.

As you can see I am not experienced at all, just learning.

edit: Thanks.
As i am saying before, the code runs perfect if i launch it from console.
I give it complete permissions (777) to everybody, just in case and for testing. The script has execution enabled but only a chmod +x, maybe something else is needed...
here is the code. As i said the script in the remote machine asks for private and public ip's and put it in a rpi database, after that he starts a reverse tunneling (or not) Launch it from /etc/rc.local and script is stored at /usr/local/games

```
#!/bin/bash
   wget -q --tries=10 --timeout=20 --spider http://google.com
   if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then

    publica=$(curl http://ipecho.net/plain)

    sleep 0.25s

    privada1= while IFS=$': \t' read -a line ;do

    [ -z "${line%inet}" ] && ip=${line[${#line[1]}>4?1:2]} &&
    [ "${ip#127.0.0.1}" ] && privada1=$ip

  done< <(LANG=C /sbin/ifconfig)


    fecha=$(date +%F_%X)


    sleep 0.15

    nombre=$(hostname)

       sleep 0.15s

 curl --data "nombre=$nombre&fecha=$fecha&publica=$publica&privada1=$privada1&privada2=$privada2&privada3=$privada3&privada4=$privada4&press=envia" http://www.xxxxxxxxx.xx/xxx.php


 while [[ $(autossh -p xxxx -R 10101:localhost:22 xx@xxxxxxxxx.xx -fN) -ne 0 ]]; do

     ping -c3 xxxxxxxxx.xx

       if ($? -eq 0) then
       autossh -p xxxx  -R 10101:localhost:22 xx@xxxxxxxxx.xx -fN;
      else
     ping -c3 xxxxxx.xxx
     fi  
  done
  else bash -x /etc/rc.local 

  fi

exit 0
```

Comment: You should paste the relevant code so we could see how exactly you attempt to create the tunnel (you may obfuscate IPs etc. if you need). [Edit your question](http://superuser.com/posts/1134409/edit) and paste the code there. About your problem: one common cause a script runs normally but not during startup is forgetting there is very limited, user-independent environment during startup. You cannot rely on `$PATH`, `~/` etc. Still, without knowing your actual code I cannot tell if it's the issue here.

Answer (score 3):

Try this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
remote_host=rpi.local
remote_port=10022
local_port=22
cmd="ssh -fN -R ${remote_port}:localhost:${local_port} ${remote_host}"

while true; do
    pgrep -fx "$cmd" >/dev/null 2>&1 || $cmd
    sleep 10
done
```

Notes:

- Adjust remote host and the ports as needed.
- The script constructs a full `ssh` command line in `cmd`.
- The script repeatedly (every 10 seconds) checks if a process exists executing that exact command line, and if not, it starts one.
- The `ssh` will run in the background because of `-f`.
- Invoke the script from `/etc/rc.local`.
- To kill the tunnel, first kill the script, then the `ssh` process.
- Needless to say, you need passphrase-less keys for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

OK so for someone who is stuck at this point or something. 
Thanks to a friend, he gave me the clue. 
rc.local launches scripts as root. so the command for launching the ssh tunnel, autossh in my case, has to be launched as other user.

Making sudo -u "youruser"  will do the job.
Thanks to all.